# Android App Manifest merger failed Facebook and Firebase

Tags: android, facebook, firebase

I'm working on a social app (Facebook and Firebase).

Once I added the firebase gradle path, I got this error:

```
Error:Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugManifest'.
```

> Manifest merger failed : Attribute activity#com.facebook.FacebookActivity@theme value=(@android:style/Theme.Translucent.NoTitleBar) from AndroidManifest.xml:85:13-72
>       is also present at [com.firebaseui:firebase-ui-auth:0.6.0] AndroidManifest.xml:69:13-58 value=(@style/FirebaseUI.Translucent).
>       Suggestion: add 'tools:replace="android:theme"' to  element at AndroidManifest.xml:81:9-85:75 to override.

`build.gradle` file:

```
compile 'com.firebaseui:firebase-ui:0.6.0'
compile 'com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:4.0.0'
```

Mainfest file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
package="com.friendture.apps.android.friendture">

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SEND_SMS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_SMS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.providers.gsf.permission.READ_GSERVICES" />

<application
    android:name=".Init"
    android:allowBackup="true"
    tools:replace="android:theme"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
    <meta-data
        android:name="com.google.android.geo.API_KEY"
        android:value="*****" />
    <meta-data
        android:name="com.facebook.sdk.ApplicationId"
        android:value="******" />

    <activity android:name=".Activity.SplashScreenActivity">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name=".Activity.ProfileActivity"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_profile" />

    <activity
        android:name="com.facebook.FacebookActivity"
        android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|screenLayout|screenSize|orientation"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Translucent.NoTitleBar" />
    <activity android:name=".Activity.PasswordActivity" />
    <activity android:name=".Activity.SelectFromListActivity" />
    <activity android:name=".Activity.CompleteFacebookActivity"></activity>
</application>
```

Comment: can you post your manifest file

Comment: @NayanSrivastava it has been updated.

Comment: Did you tried to add 'tools:replace="android:theme" in manifest?

Answer (score 12):

Ever since we added **firebase-ui-auth** to our project, this error has shown up and if it's not properly fixed, causes facebook activity to crash !

To fix it, update the manifest (notice the new "tools" attribute):

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
          xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
          package="YOUR_PACKAGE">

    <!-- Facebook API Key -->
    <meta-data
        tools:replace="android:value"
        android:name="com.facebook.sdk.ApplicationId"
        android:value="@string/facebook_app_id" />

    <activity
        android:name="com.facebook.FacebookActivity"
        android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|screenLayout|screenSize|orientation"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:launchMode="singleInstance"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait"/>
```

Answer (score 7):

The combination of two earlier answers by Nayan Srivastava and MhmdAljobairi worked for me:

```
<meta-data
                android:name="com.facebook.sdk.ApplicationId"
                tools:replace="android:value"
                android:value="@string/facebook_app_id"
        />
```

Answer (score 0):

As hint is already there in logcat response, just add `'tools:replace="android:theme"'` to your `application` node in `manifest` and you are good to go.

Comment: Still I got the same problem.

Comment: can u update the manifest file now in question and please include namespaces as well

Comment: The problem has been solved, I just moved `'tools:replace="android:theme"'` to the facebook activity tag

Comment: This is a weird PITA bug - what's the root cause for it? Firebase has the same xml tag in their manifest?